# OData in .Net Core 2.2 : how to get total number of items?

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I've created a new .NET Core 2.2 web app, using OData v7.1.

I've got it up and running and can already use $top, $skip, ...

I'm trying to get $count to work properly now, but I'm completely lost at how to do it.

I've already tried following several links, all of them either no longer compile, or do not produce the result I want.

What I have :

in **StartUp.cs**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.EnableDependencyInjection();
                routes.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(null).Count();
            });
```

in my **Controller class:**

```
        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult All()
        {
            var assets = _service.GetAllAssets();
            return Ok(assets);
        }
```

This returns all assets and I can use $top and $skip no problem. Now how do I add $count=true, or any other method that will allow me to also return my total count? What am I doing wrong?

Sample url that works:
http://localhost/api/Assets/All?$top=20&$skip=20

Url that does not work:
http://localhost/api/Assets/All?$count=true
(it returns all assets)

The current result is:

```
[{Item One}, {Item Two}]
```

The desired result for me would be:

```
[Count : 4, 
 Items: [{Item One}, {Item Two}
]
```

Comment: OData is supposed to work on top of an IQueryable and adds Select, Where, etc as needed. I suspect that `GetAliases` returns a list of all items instead of an `IQueryable`

Comment: Have you tried the OData examples in the [ASP.NET Core OData announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/), especially the `Query the Resources` example ?

Comment: Count() will only work on a list or an array.  You put count after MaxTop(null) which returns a singleton.  That is why you are getting an error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I have read that page before posting here. Problem is this line: ".MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());". This produces this error: "Cannot use 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataRoute' with Endpoint Routing.", because Endpoint Routing has become standard for .NET Core 2.2

Comment: @StevenLemmens you should explain that in the question itself. If routing changed since 2.0, the thing that needs changing is routing and `Startup.cs`, not the actions.

Comment: Check [this example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/supercharging-asp-net-core-api-with-odata/) and the OData Github [samples](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/WebApiCore/ODataActionSample/ODataActionSample/Startup.cs). They use `services.AddOData()` for .NET Core 2.1 projects

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
public IActionResult GetData(ODataQueryOptions<YourType> query)
{
    var data = _context.SetOfYourType;
    return Ok(new
    {
        Items = query.ApplyTo(data),
        Count = query.Count?.GetEntityCount(query.Filter?.ApplyTo(data, new ODataQuerySettings()) ?? data)
    });
}
```

This is basically produce the same result as using PageResult, at least in terms of $expand,$select and $count.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning ODataQueryOptions<T> - exactly what I needed.

Comment: You save my day, thank you! Worth to mention, that Count property will be filled only if query contains "$count=true" parameter

Answer (score 0):

You return wrong type, go this way:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IQueryable<YourType> All()
    {
        var assets = _service.GetAllAssets(); //Where assets is IQueryable
        return assets;
    }
```

OData middleware will made rest for you. Also in this approach if you make skip/take/select it is evaluate on SQL level.

Comment: Sorry of course you need return assets without Ok(). I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I removed my initial comment !

Comment: But this does not make a difference, how do I get my total count now? If I add $count=true to my query, it makes no difference and all data is returned?

Comment: Do you happen to have any ideas to my last question? How do I get the total count of assets now? Calling my URL like this: http://localhost:xxx/api/Assets/All?$count=true, does not do anything. How do I get the total number of Assets that conform to my query?

Comment: I had the same issue and for me, adding the model type as the generic parameter to IQueryable fixed it for me